# Find the individual ages of the $10$ persons under given condition.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, contest-math, solution-verification

> In a group of ten persons, each person is asked to write the sum of the ages of all the other
> $9$ persons. If all the ten sums form the $9$-element set $\{82, 83, 84, 85, 87, 89, 90, 91, 92\}$ find the individual ages of the persons (assuming them to be whole numbers of years).

This is a question from RMO $1993$. Not sure if this has been asked before, but I wanted to verify my approach.

***My Approach:***

It is evident that the set of the sums provided by persons must be a $10$-element gorup provided that the ages of all of the people are different. Since we have a $9$-element set, the ages of two persons among the ten must be same.

This means that those two people must have written the same sums.

Now the total sum of the $9$-element set is $783$. Suppose the sum which was repeated (say $x$) is also added to $783$.

In $783+x=9T$ (T is the toal sum of ages of all ten people), the age of each person must have been added over $9$ times (through each sum other than the one written by him).

$$\therefore 783+x\equiv 0\pmod{9}$$
$$783\equiv 0\pmod{9}\Rightarrow x\equiv0 \pmod{9}$$
Now the only element of the $9$-element set satisfying the above condition is $90$

$$\therefore 9T=783+90=873\Rightarrow T=97$$
Subtracting each sum from the $9$-element set gives the individual age of the persons.

$\therefore$ The individual ages of the persons are $\{15,14,13,12,10,8,7,7,6,5\}$

Please check my approach and provide suggestions. Also please provide any alternative approach if possible.

***THANKS***

Comment: The approach looks perfectly correct. The computations are right too.

Comment: So is it enough rigorous to be written as a solution to a contest problem? I'm sorry but I'm never confident whether my solution is rigorous enough or not.

Comment: @DevanshKamra: It’s rigorous enough.

Comment: Thanks for assistance. Also please feel free to provide any alternative solution you may have.